# the usage of the word "platform"

Tags: word-usage

I'm trying to write a paragraph explaining an internet-of-things platform **(through/on)** which users can interact with their houses using a smartphone application (for instance when the owner walks in, the house detects that it's him and turns on the tv to his favorite channel or turns on the lights etc.) (can i use platform like this; on+ platform ?)

I'd like to know how i can incorporate the word platform in my sentence. 
i have some ideas :

> the platform enables users to interact with their houses
>
> using the platform users can interact with their houses
>
> the platform allows users to interact with their houses
>
> users can interact with their houses on (or via/through) this platform

but I'm not really sure about any of the above.

I did some research on the web and went through a couple of dictionaries but almost all the examples I found refereed to the word platform as a solid foundation on which people or things stand which is not the usage in this sentence. honestly i couldn't find a single example where the word platform was used with a preposition (on/through/for .... )

the following is from Webster online dictionary :

Definition of platform
1 : plan, design
2 : a declaration of the principles on which a group of persons stands; especially : a declaration of principles and policies adopted by a political party or a candidate
3 a (1) : a usually raised horizontal flat surface; especially : a raised flooring
(2) : a device or structure incorporating or providing a platform; especially : such a structure on legs used for offshore drilling (as for oil)
b : a place or opportunity for public discussion
4 a : a usually thick layer (as of cork) between the inner sole and outer sole of a shoe
b : a shoe having such a sole
5 a : a vehicle (such as a satellite or aircraft) used for a particular purpose or to carry a usually specified kind of equipment
**b : operating system; also : the computer architecture and equipment using a particular operating system**

from all the definitions above only the bold one makes sense in my sentence. 
please help ! thanks :)

Comment: The definition in bold is certainly the correct definition for anything relating to software, but we can't really comment on whether it is appropriate for the sentence that you want to use it in until you edit your question to add the  sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer - No, "**platform**" isn't the right word in your context.

The long version:

"**[platform](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/49362/platform)**" is "*A hardware and/or software architecture that serves as a foundation or base*" or most often "*the computer architecture and equipment using a particular operating system*" or "*A software enviroment that is used to write applications and run them*". A platform in IT is something on which something else is built or that provides the possibility of building something. Android is a platform as any other OS. The term is closely related to the term "environment".

In your context words like "**software**" or "**system**" would be more likely.

Comment: thanks. how about when the word platform is right in a context, are any of the sentences i mentioned (in the block-quote) correct ? I'm aware that in the sentence I'm trying to write the word platform makes little sense but I'm thinking about a context in which the word is actually meaningful, in that case, can it be used in any of the structures i provided ?

Comment: @ShahabSamkan No, only, "The platform provides software that enables the users to interact with their houses"